# Help optimising PGSQL query

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, postgresql-performance

I have a slow Postgres (v15.3) query and I can't seem to get to the bottom of why. I've considered partitioning, but articles suggest that with a 10GB database partitioning isn't required and it seems like a real pain to set up on a production database.

The tables are 'large' but small in the grand scheme of things compared to other PGSQL databases.

student_tracks has 37m rows in it, this is a months worth of data, so grows at a reasonable rate. However, we'll only retain the last 3 months worth of data. So say 100m rows on average.

students has 10m rows in it and like the above is 1 months worth of data, with a cap at 3 months.

The problem is, producing monthly reports (although ideally want to be able to run 3/6 months reports, although 1 month is fine for now) on these tables. The current query is as follows:

```
select 
  "students"."id", 
  "students"."student_type_id", 
  "students"."user_agent", 
  "students"."user_agent_is_mobile", 
  (
    select 
      TO_CHAR(
        MAX(student_tracks.enrolled_at) :: DATE, 
        'Mon yy'
      ) 
    from 
      "student_tracks" 
    where 
      student_tracks.student_id = students.id 
      and "student_tracks"."enrolled_at" between '2023-02-01' 
      and '2023-05-30'
  ) as "last_enrolled", 
  (
    select 
      1 
    from 
      "chats" 
    where 
      chats.student_id = students.id 
      and "chats"."created_at" between '2023-02-01' 
      and '2023-05-30' 
    limit 
      1
  ) as "has_chat", 
  (
    select 
      1 
    from 
      "chat_reports" 
      inner join "chats" on "chats"."id" = "chat_reports"."chat_id" 
    where 
      chats.student_id = students.id 
      and "chat_reports"."created_at" between '2023-02-01' 
      and '2023-05-30' 
    limit 
      1
  ) as "has_chat_report" 
from 
  "students" 
where 
  exists (
    select 
      1 
    from 
      "student_tracks" 
    where 
      student_tracks.student_id = students.id 
      and "student_tracks"."enrolled_at" between '2023-02-01' 
      and '2023-05-30'
  )
```

This query is taking 352 seconds and returns 7.8m records querying a read replica which is idle apart from these test queries.

The query plan for the above is as follows:

```
Gather  (cost=1049084.91..31608500.92 rows=702040 width=215) (actual time=15461.166..352171.314 rows=7132605 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=80066569 read=434196
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=774055.958
  ->  Parallel Hash Semi Join  (cost=1048084.91..1693374.65 rows=292517 width=175) (actual time=15436.019..22445.654 rows=2377535 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: ((students.id)::text = (student_tracks.student_id)::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=688458 read=354409
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=658645.994
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on students  (cost=0.00..426288.80 rows=4323980 width=175) (actual time=0.008..3101.324 rows=3517892 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=28393 read=354409
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=658645.994
        ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=894892.34..894892.34 rows=12255405 width=32) (actual time=15361.488..15361.489 rows=9815722 loops=3)
              Buckets: 33554432  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2337216kB
              Buffers: shared hit=659943
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on student_tracks  (cost=0.00..894892.34 rows=12255405 width=32) (actual time=0.019..6883.347 rows=9815722 loops=3)
"                    Filter: ((connected_at >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (connected_at <= '2023-05-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2982354
                    Buffers: shared hit=659943
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Result  (cost=4.69..4.70 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=7132605)
          Buffers: shared hit=35596058 read=66967
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=86084.242
          InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
            ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..4.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=7132605)
                  Buffers: shared hit=35596058 read=66967
                  I/O Timings: shared/local read=86084.242
"                  ->  Index Scan Backward using ""~student_tracks-a1b7f7a8"" on student_tracks student_tracks_1  (cost=0.56..173.61 rows=42 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=7132605)"
"                        Index Cond: (((student_id)::text = (students.id)::text) AND (connected_at IS NOT NULL) AND (connected_at >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (connected_at <= '2023-05-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
                        Buffers: shared hit=35596058 read=66967
                        I/O Timings: shared/local read=86084.242
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=7132605)
          Buffers: shared hit=21556886 read=8996
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=10695.264
"          ->  Index Scan using ""~chats-5ca320c0"" on chats  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=7132605)"
"                Index Cond: (((student_id)::text = (students.id)::text) AND (created_at >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2023-05-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
                Buffers: shared hit=21556886 read=8996
                I/O Timings: shared/local read=10695.264
  SubPlan 4
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.85..29.36 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=7132605)
          Buffers: shared hit=22225167 read=3824
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=18630.459
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..29.36 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=7132605)
                Buffers: shared hit=22225167 read=3824
                I/O Timings: shared/local read=18630.459
"                ->  Index Scan using ""~chats-4f9644a3"" on chats chats_1  (cost=0.43..12.46 rows=2 width=33) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=7132605)"
                      Index Cond: ((student_id)::text = (students.id)::text)
                      Buffers: shared hit=21581799 read=2191
                      I/O Timings: shared/local read=16709.616
                ->  Index Scan using chat_leads_pkey on chat_leads  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=184067)
                      Index Cond: ((chat_id)::text = (chats_1.id)::text)
"                      Filter: ((created_at >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2023-05-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                      Buffers: shared hit=643368 read=1633
                      I/O Timings: shared/local read=1920.842
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=266
Planning Time: 0.876 ms
Execution Time: 353064.689 ms
```

I would really welcome any suggestions on how to improve this query. I've tried all sorts of postgres query plan analyzers online and just can't get it down to a reasonable timeframe.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your relevant table definitions and index definitions to your Post.

Comment: Why is 6 minutes too long to wait for a monthly report?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by converting the subqueries into joins:

```
SELECT
  "students"."id", 
  "students"."student_type_id", 
  "students"."user_agent", 
  "students"."user_agent_is_mobile", 
  TO_CHAR(
        MAX(student_tracks.enrolled_at) :: DATE, 
        'Mon yy'
  ) as "last_enrolled", 
  ( COUNT("chats"."id") > 0 ) as "has_chat", 
  ( COUNT("chat_reports"."chat_id") > 0 ) as "has_chat_report" 
FROM "students" 
JOIN "student_tracks" ON student_tracks.student_id = students.id 
LEFT JOIN "chats" ON (chats.student_id = students.id and "chats"."created_at" between '2023-02-01' and '2023-05-30')
LEFT JOIN "chat_reports" ON ("chats"."id" = "chat_reports"."chat_id" and "chat_reports"."created_at" between '2023-02-01' and '2023-05-30' )
WHERE
      "student_tracks"."enrolled_at" between '2023-02-01' and '2023-05-30'
GROUP BY     
  "students"."id", 
  "students"."student_type_id", 
  "students"."user_agent", 
  "students"."user_agent_is_mobile"
;
```

Some obvious indexes would be:

```
students (id)
students_tracks (student_id)
chats (student_id, id)
chat_reports (chat_id)
```

Try this and, if the result is not yet fast enough, post all your index definitions and an updated query plan.